# Fake portion of the path in the URL using PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In some websites I see something like the following:

`http://example.com/bills/c4grSxby6Eysk0TREcXKZDDfRse0XB/yourbill.php`

The random String in the middle of that path is changed whenever the browser window is closed (session ended).

I need to know the logic of creating such faking `URL` and some code example to make it.

Comment: `.htaccess` make proper redirection + `routing` class (which uses, i guess, `session_id` variable).

Comment: Search `php routing` or `php pretty urls`.

Comment: @YousufMemon and by the way, what's the technical definition of such action?

Comment: @i-CONICA but URL rewriting is going to be for fixed paths, is not it?

Comment: Fixed paths? I don't understand. Any portion of the url can be defined as a get variable when rewritten. It's not necessarily anything to do with paths. Unless I've misunderstood you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for URL rewrites, for example, using Apache's Mod Rewrite. This isn't a PHP specific thing.

What you can do is say you have a URL like...

```
mysite.com/bills/c4grSxby6Eysk0TREcXKZDDfRse0XB/yourbill.php
```

where c4grSxby6Eysk0TREcXKZDDfRse0XB is the session ID, with the rewrite, it's actually being passed to...

```
mysite.com/bills/yourbill.php?session=c4grSxby6Eysk0TREcXKZDDfRse0XB
```

and handled normally, it's just a different URL in the browser.

Assuming you are using Apache and have the rewrite module enabled, you can define rewrite rules in your .htaccess file. The rule for such a rewrite would be:

```
RewriteRule ^mysite.com/bills/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/yourbill.php$ mysite.com/bills/yourbill.php?session=$1
```

Untested, but should work, where $i is the value of the ith (in this case $1 is the first) regular expression group (the value inside the brackets).

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache's mod_rewrite, the first part of the url will be a variable, which will map to a file which will deal with it. It'll be rewritten as such, internally: /bills/index.php?str=c4grSxby6Eysk0TREcXKZDDfRse0XB or similar...

Comment: But the string should be changed with sessions?